# height 100 % with scrollbar and invisible content

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with a div with 100% height. In that div i've got table records but the last 5 records are not visible because the scrollbar stops before it reach those records.

An example of the html structure:

[JS fiddle](http://tinyurl.com/ohmu49s)

It looks like that the list-header causes the problem because when I remove that div the last records are visible. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: All items are visible in code snippet. Maybe the problem is the parent div ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="list">
        <div class="list-table">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr><td>header</td></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>tesdst</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test</td></tr>
                <tr><td>2nd</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Last</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use the `thead` instead of the `div` you created this would be the best practice, since you can still use buttons and everything in the thead table cells.

Anyways :

You need to make list-table smaller 90% Work fine.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1p1w2rq/4/)

**Explaination :**

You parent Div "list" has a height of 100%, your "list-header" has a height of 70px and your "list-table" also has a height of 100%. The 100% of the "list-table" + the 70px height of the "list-header" equal more than 100%. So you need to either make your "list" bigger or the children in it smaller - rember you always need to split the heights of the parent to the childs to make them fit. Was that understandable ?

Comment: The list header cannot be part of the table because it contains buttons en other stuff...

Comment: You didnt state that in your question. Everyone would think you made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `position:fixed` in your `.main` class? Try without that

Answer (score 0):

```
.list-table {
    height:80vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```